# sort files as per their dated names at the same time create filehandles for each file in perl

Tags: perl

I have the about 1000 files named as

CU20130404160033.TXT
CU20130405160027.TXT ....
CUYYYYMMDDHHMMSS.TXT

I need to append all the files into single file as per names where where min(date) to max(date)

How can i make the programm efficient where i should sort the files as per their Dates and create filehandles.

```
opendir (DIR, $Directory) or die $!;

@files = grep { (!/^\./) && -f "$Directory/$_" } readdir(DIR);

chdir($Directory);

#create an array of open filehandles.
@fh = map { open my $f, $_ or die "Cant open $_:$!"; $f } @files;

#create new file for output

open $out_file , ">$filename" or die "cant open new file $!";
```

Comment: can you show us the line up of the output file? do you just want to sort the files and take their data or do you want to create a file (csv or what) where one of the columns is the date the data comes from.

Comment: i just need to sort the files. i may not worried about internal data. the only thing is i need to sort the files form min(date) to max(date) of the format what i have  mentioned and i should create file handles.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should be helpful.

```
opendir (DIR, $dir);
@dir=readdir(DIR);
closedir(DIR);

#Sort file list by modification time and write to an output file    
open(my $fh, ">", "output.txt") or die $!;
print $fh sort{ -M "$dir/$b" <=> -M "$dir/$a" }(@dir);
close $fh;
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose this script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

#1. Set up the general values
my $directory = "... the dir ...";
my $out_file  = "... the out file ...";

#2. Fill an array with the names of your files
opendir(my $dh, $directory) or die $!;
while( my $file = readdir($dh) ) {
    push @files, $file;
}
closedir $dh;

#3. Sort the array 
@files = sort {$a cmp $b} @files;

#4. Open the target file
open $out_file , '>', $filename or die $!;

#5. Iterate for each input file, open it, 
#   and write line by line its contents to the target
foreach my $filename(@files) {
   open my $ifh, '<', $filename or die $!;
   while( my $line = <$ifh> ) {
      print $out_file $line;
   }
   close $ifh;
}

#6. Close the target
close $out_file;
```